# Attempt to cast std::chrono::duration gives "rep cannot be a duration" compilation error

Tags: c++, casting, c++-chrono

Sure I'm doing something dumb here but I'm having trouble compiling my simple stopwatch class.  The error is:

> /usr/include/c++/4.9/chrono:246:2: error: static assertion failed: rep
>   cannot be a duration

I want to cast the difference in time between two std::chrono::high_resolution_clock to milliseconds.  I'm sure this code used to work (false memory or perhaps better standards impl with 2015 over 2013).

The [repo is here](http://cpp.sh/25w2h).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

class Stopwatch final
{
public:

    using elapsed_resolution = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    using elapsed_duration = std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::milliseconds>;

    Stopwatch()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        reset_time = clock.now();
    }

    elapsed_duration Elapsed()
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<elapsed_resolution>(clock.now() - reset_time);
    }

private:

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point reset_time;
};

int main(void)
{
    auto s = Stopwatch();

    std::cout << s.Elapsed().count() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The problem is `using elapsed_duration = std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::milliseconds>;`. Please read the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). Btw, that's obvious from the error messages of modern compilers: https://wandbox.org/permlink/rOfqAkm9XqvZXpkI

Comment: I want to return a time interval.  elapsed_duration is a time interval, no?

Comment: No, as the error says, the representation of some duration may not be another duration.

Comment: I don't understand, mostly because if you read the docs you'll see this being done in the duration_cast example.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find said example. If it should exist, it would be wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see what the error is.  The return type of Elapsed() should be elapsed_resolution, not elapsed_duration.  I'm returning milliseconds.

Comment: On duration_cast page there's, "auto int_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);", i.e. conversion of t2-t1 to a duration.  I suppose I want to return a duration like this.

Comment: Well, `std::chrono::duration_cast` and `std::chrono::duration` are two different things taking different arguments...

Comment: Sorry, I assumed duration_cast would cast to a duration.

Comment: It does. Please re-read my second comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line here:

```
using elapsed_duration = std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::milliseconds>;
```

needs to be something like this:

```
using elapsed_duration = std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>;
```